# Union Query in Access 2.0

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I'm trying to create a query that will run in Access 2.0.

The main table has two title columns and two credit columns.  A person will show up in either Title A or Title B and will get credits for A or B.  Only Title A gets credit for Credit A and Title B for Credit B

```
**Title A   Title B Credit A    Credit B**
James   Sam     1   0
Jason   James   1   1
Justin  Sara    1   1
Sam     James   1   0
Justin  Jason   1   1
Sara    James   1   0
Jason   Sam     0   1
```

I'd like a result set in Access 2.0 that has the persons name with total credits for A and B

```
**Person    Credits**
Jason   2
James   2
Sam     2
Sara    2
Justin  2
```

what is the best way to do this in access?  create two separate queries for A and B and union together and group?

[Click here for a better picture of the Table Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ClK.png)

Comment: The UNION and GROUP approach that you suggest is the way I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.

Making two query with SUM and name by `titleA` and `titleB` ,then use UNION Combine two species. you can get their totle Credits by Person

```
SELECT Person,sum(totle) Credits
FROM 
(
    SELECT TitleA Person,SUM(CreditA) totle
    FROM T
    GROUP BY TitleA
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT TitleB Person,SUM(CreditB) totle
    FROM T
    GROUP BY TitleB
) t
GROUP BY Person
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/331f2/1*

Comment: you can do the sum only once. But this will work too. upvoted +1

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ Yes,you can `UNION ALL`  `TitleA` and `TitleB` then `SUM`  :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes tou are correct! You combine all person and credit columns using UNION ALL then do GROUP BY. Get the sum to total the credit column.

```
SELECT person, sum(credit) as credits
FROM 
  (
    SELECT TitleA as person,CreditA as credit
    FROM T
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT TitleB,CreditB
   FROM T
  ) t
GROUP BY Person
```

Comment: If I use a union, it works in Access 2016, but fails in when loaded into Access 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Get error 'Syntax Error in FROM Clause' in Access 2.0

```
SELECT FlightData.Person, FlightData.TailNumber, FlightData.Aircraft, Sum(FlightData.Landings) AS TotalLandings
FROM (
SELECT [Flight Data].Date, [Flight Data].Pilot AS Person, [Flight Data].[Aircraft Number] AS TailNumber, Aircraft.[Aircraft Type] AS Aircraft, [Flight Data].[Pilot Landings] AS Landings FROM [Flight Data] INNER JOIN Aircraft ON [Flight Data].[Aircraft Number] = Aircraft.[Tail Number]
UNION ALL
SELECT [Flight Data].Date, [Flight Data].CoPilot as Person,[Flight Data].[Aircraft Number] AS TailNumber, Aircraft.[Aircraft Type] as Aircraft, [Flight Data].[CoPilot Landings]AS Landings FROM [Flight Data]  INNER JOIN Aircraft ON [Flight Data].[Aircraft Number] = Aircraft.[Tail Number] 
)  AS FlightData
WHERE FlightData.[date] Between [Start Date] And [End Date]
GROUP BY FlightData.Person, FlightData.TailNumber, FlightData.Aircraft;
```

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I was able to create the union as its own query and then reference that and access 2.0 liked it better